# AspNet Core 3.0 and 3.1 : Enable runtime compilation for Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

Since ASP.Net Core version 3.0 and higher:

A) Editing a Razor View (.cshtml) file while running the application does not apply the changes until restart.

B) Looks like edit and continue is not working.

**IDE and Version:**
Microsoft Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For this issue, I suggest you try to install package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` and then configure `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation` in `Startup.cs` like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
}
```

For this issue, you could trace by [Breaking changes to runtime compilation for Razor views and Razor Pages #343](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/343)

Comment: Thank you for you quick response.  cshtml page update problem solved by adding Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation service.  still looking for a solution for first issue.

Comment: Figures, yet another thing that used to "just work" is now yet another package we have to install.

Comment: Now, this change is documented as well. [Razor file compilation in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Im getting an error whe try to install the Razor Runtime package.
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation 5.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package. 
Any one encountered this ?

Comment: @Sajithd You can install version 3.1.10

Answer (score 4):

> Please use NuGet package
> **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation Version 3.1.7**
> that is compatible with **ASP.Net Core 3.1** and apply following line of code in Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddControllersWithViews();            
      services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Note as indicated in the ["Razor file compilation in ASP.NET Core"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.1) posted by Givi, if you just want this feature for ***rapid development***, you can enable this just for development and not for production by NOT adding

```
.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
```

to Startup.cs, and instead adding these environment variables to your  `launchSettings.json`

```
"ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" = "Development"
```

only for our integrated development environment (Dev appserver deployed through DevOps) and use

```
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" = "Local"
```

for individual developer's local development (in an accompanying `appsettings.Local.json` config file).

I'm happy to report that `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"` does not strictly need to be set to `"Development"` and that runtime compilation works for `"Local"` (and presumably whatever is the name you use for the environment you develop under).

But one thing I found was that although I added `ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES` to `launchSettings.json`, it was being removed (and thus not working) by the project properties Debug tab until I added the variable there (and now it works great).

Answer (score 0):

I was working on an asp.net core 3.1 project that was somehow modular and each module had their own Controller & Views. Modules where living in a folder in solution root folder. In such a case only adding `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation` method didn't helped me and I had to configure `FileProviders`. Just wanted to note the right configuration for me was to add every modules folder path, actually folder that contains `.csproj` file in it, to `FileProviders` for some one like me wasting a lot of time to configure.