# is it possible to edit code while debugging in visual studio code , like in eclipse (java)

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

[is it possible to edit code while debugging in visual studio, like in eclipse (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672961/is-it-possible-to-edit-code-while-debugging-in-visual-studio-like-in-eclipse-j)

since similar question is asked above, i need to know if i can do this on visual studio code not visual studio

i  tried using the debugger and when i changed some lines its needed for me to restart node server to apply changes

Comment: it depends on the debugger used, VSC is just a GUI front end of the debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem this is not able yet on Visual Studio Code, i'll show you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/edit-and-continue?view=vs-2022

[image]